# Paste text in Photoshop without styling

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I would like to copy text in one text element (A) in Photoshop and paste it into another text element (B) without influencing the style. I would like to keep the styling of element B when I paste.

Photoshop instead copies the styling from A with.

Any keyboard shortcut to make this work?

Comment: If there isn't a "paste as plain text" option, I just paste the words into notepad to clear styling then copy again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there's no such shortcut in Photoshop. Paste in a plain text editor, copy from there and paste again in Photoshop.

If you're on a Mac and have ClipMenu installed, simply hitting cmd+shift+v and selecting the same text should clear up the text formatting.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this one step faster. Instead of the text editor, Use Photoshop's Font drop-down for clearing the text styling!

See details here:
http://futurice.com/blog/photoshop-productivity-hack-paste-and-match-style-alternative

> 1. Copy the text you need to paste, from wherever (web, other app, other Photoshop file).
> 2. Select the Ps Type tool (you would be doing this anyway, because you're pasting into a text object).
> 3. Paste into the Font drop-down. (this is the "hack" part)
> 4. Select All from the Font drop-down and Copy again.
> 5. Hit Escape. (to revert the Font drop-down selection to what it was before and prevent getting an error)
> 6. Paste into your destination text object.

Comment: Can you expand your answer to explain how to do that?

Comment: That's actually a pretty good hack! You should list the steps in your answer though, links can easily be taken down or moved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the application Ditto - http://ditto-cp.sourceforge.net/ and create a shortcut for pasting plain text. It works for windows.

Comment: Hi Mathew, welcome to GDSE and thanks for contributing. We like seeing long answers here, so although your answer is correct, could you maybe substantiate it a bit more? Tell us what the program is, why and how it works. Users are hesitant to just click any link and a more substantiated answer can help legitimate the link. Please keep contributing and thanks for your time and effort. If you have any questions, see the [help] for more info, comment on a question or answer, or ping us in [chat].

Answer (score 0):

Go into text edit mode > right click > paste without formatting (PS CC2018+)
[image]